# Use grep to find a specific pattern in a line

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I am trying to find a specific pattern in a text file using grep inside a bourne shell script

The style is: `word1 word2 word3`

I want to print everything that is not of that style. So far I used

```
grep -e '[[:space:]]\{2,\}' somefile
```

to find more than 2 empty spaces between the words, but I cannot figure out how to make it so that the 3 word per line limit is retained.

My other method would be to also count how many words there are per line and if it exceeds 3, to print the line. Or to check for a white space at the end of the 3rd word, but I am unsure how that would be formatted.

Comment: The purpose of grep is to find lines containing specific patterns. Maybe try to think harder about the title for your next question?

Comment: Pedantic note: it's unlikely you are actually using the Bourne shell, but rather some POSIX-compliant shell named `sh`, which has more features than were present in the original Bourne shell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you wanted, but here:

> ```
> ]$ cat input
> one
>
> one two
> one two three
> one two three four
>
> ]$ grep -v -e "^[^[:space:]]\+ [^[:space:]]\+ [^[:space:]]\+$" input
> one
>
> one two
> one two three four
> ```

We match:

- any number of not spaces: `[^[:space:]]\+`
- until we get a space
- repeated 3 times
- all this should be in one line: `^...$`
- and we negate this with `-v` option

Comment: Hey, this works perfectly! just how do i get the output to come out on seperate lines instead of in one go? I use echo in the bourne shell script

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you asking how to make `echo` print out multiple lines?

Comment: @thunderfox Sounds like you are doing something like `g=$(grep stuff); echo $g`. There are situations where it makes sense to capture the output into a variable, but without access to your code and/or your reasons, this sounds like just another [useless use of backticks](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks). If it's legitimate, proper quoting should help; `echo "$g"` with double quotes. Otherwise, `grep` by itself is quite capable of printing the matches.